# How to display error messages from server side fluent validation AND client side validation at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have this fluent validation rule:

```
public EmployeeAbsenceValidator() {
    RuleFor(a => a.DateTo)
        .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(a => a.DateFrom)
        .WithMessage("The end date cannot be before the start date.");
}
```

In the Create POST-method in the controller, I'm validating the dates and saving to the database and redirecting to a details view for the employee if the dates are valid, or returning to the create-absence-view if they are not:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    EmployeeAbsenceValidator validator = new EmployeeAbsenceValidator();
    ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(employeeAbsence);
    if (result.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(employeeAbsence);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Employees");
    }
    else
    {
        result.AddToModelState(ModelState, null); // Passing error message to model state
        return View(employeeAbsence);
    }
}
```

This is the create-absence-view:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="Percentage" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Percentage" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Percentage" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="DateFrom" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="DateFrom" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DateFrom" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="DateTo" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="DateTo" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DateTo" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" value="Save">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

If `Percentage` is filled in correctly, and the `DateTo` is prior to `DateFrom`, the error message from fluent validation is shown on the date. But if the `Percentage` is not valid, only the client side error message on `Percentage` is shown. I guess that's because the server does'nt know about the invalidity of the dates, seeing as the form hasn't been submitted yet. How can I get both error messages? (Please tell me I don't need to write any JQuery...)

Comment: You cannot. The only thing you can do is implement the same validation client-side, and yes, that requires jQuery, as the client-side validation utilizes the jQuery Validation library.

Answer (score 0):

FluentValidation is a server-side framework. Not all rules defined in FluentValidation will work with ASP.NET’s client-side validation. But you can add client-side validation support to Fluent Validation with Form Helper library.

https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper

Add FormHelper from Nuget Package Manager to your project.

Register FormHelper in your startup.cs

```
services.AddFormHelper();
```

Create your forms like this:

```
var formConfig = new FormConfig(ViewContext)
{
    FormId = "ProductForm",
    FormTitle = "New Product",
    Callback = "ProductFormCallback" // optional,
};

// <form id="@formConfig.FormId" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Save"
// ...

@await Html.RenderFormScript(formConfig)
```

And use this attribute on your save action for client-side validation:

```
[HttpPost, FormValidator]
public IActionResult Save(FormViewModel viewModel)
```

It's ready for usage.

You can look the github page for more information.